# Debugger stepping directly into referenced class instead of one that calls it

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I used to execute my code, I used to be able to step into the following line of code in my PC class, and it went to my GetProgramControl method, where I could step some more.

```
controls[i] = (Control)_type.InvokeMember("GetProgramControl", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, _objectInstance, _parameters);
```

For some reason, I was stepping into that at one point, and it was having trouble finding my SN.cs and I hit the link to browse to show it where it was. Ever since then, every time I step into the line above, it goes directly to the later reference of my SN class and the debugger is in a method there. Any ideas how I can get the debugger to stop in the PC class GetProgramControl method? I can't put a breakpoint there because it's outside of my class that is calling it.

I looked at the following but it's different since my SN class isn't a child of PC, it's a reference used in it. 
http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/439984-cant-step-into

I also saw this and it might be similar but it doesn't look like anyone had a solution for him: http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2932838/Can-t-step-into-method-debug-with-F11-in-Visual-St.aspx

My question is, how do I get the debugger to step directly into the PC.cs first instead of the SN.cs method that the PC.cs is calling?  I'm not sure where that info is stored or if there is something I can reset to make visual studio step into PC.cs directly.

Comment: could there possibly be a problem with both classes having the same method name..? if so then you will need to fully qualify the NameSpace or the Method, or you can use Aliasing on the NameSpace ..hard to tell without knowing or seeing the Class Definition along with how you are using the NameSpace.

Comment: It's not the same method name.  The debugger winds up in getSN() in my SN.cs, but PC.cs doesn't have that method name.

Comment: was the PC.cs code converted to a .DLL perhaps if you hit F11 does it take you to the Object Browser..?

Comment: It doesn't go to the Object Browser if I hit F11.

Comment: I figured it out!!!  I have to copy the DLL into a directory where the program looks to use it, and I recopied it, and it worked this time I ran it.  Maybe my DLL was out of date and wasn't matching up.  Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: you could also set the property of that .DLL to Copy in the project when you recompile so you don't have to manually copy it over.. Glad you figured this out.. another suggestion would be to GAC the .DLL